# routing scope problem with form_for (partial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scope, form-for

Trying to route:

```
scope :shortcut do
 resources :text_elems
end
```

Using basic scaffold with form partial

```
*_form.html.erb*
<%= form_for(@text_elem, :shortcut => @shortcut) do |f| %> 
...
```

**Problem is**: When I call the *edit* action, the form html shows as:

```
<form ... action="/25/text_elems/25">
```

**Note:** The *new* action renders the form action correctly:

```
<form ... action="/home/text_elems">
```

So it appears that my :shortcut param is getting trumped by the :id param when form_for processes it's block.  Now I am able to get the action to correctly route with the :shortcut param if I manually make the :url => {...} in the form_for block, but I would prefer to keep the code dry, plus I want to report this problem to rails if it is indeed a bug.

Can anyone else confirm this as a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can pass the values as a full hash, rather than trying to rely on the default to_param (which is what gets called if all you do is pass the @text_elem)

```
<%= form_for({:id => @text_elem.to_param, :shortcut => @shortcut}) do |f| %>
```

however, if this is actually a nested-resource, you could also do:

```
<%= form_for([@shortcut, @text_elem]) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issues and none of the above answers helped.

The last answer on this page worked for me though...

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6736-problem-with-scoped-routes-and-form_for-helper