# With Ruby on Rails 5, how can I use the same form_for partial for new & edit actions while supplying an additional parameter for routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

In my routes.rb, I have

```
scope ':account_id/' do
  resources :notes
end
```

Which makes URL's like:

```
                notes GET    /:account_id/notes(.:format)     notes#index
                      POST   /:account_id/notes(.:format)     notes#create
             new_note GET    /:account_id/notes/new(.:format)                                                         notes#new
            edit_note GET    /:account_id/notes/:id/edit(.:format)                                                    notes#edit
                 note GET    /:account_id/notes/:id(.:format)                                                         notes#show
                      PATCH  /:account_id/notes/:id(.:format)                                                         notes#update
                      PUT    /:account_id/notes/:id(.:format)                                                         notes#update
                      DELETE /:account_id/notes/:id(.:format)                                                         notes#destroy
```

In my _form.html.erb, I have this:

```
<%= form_for(@note, url: notes_path(account_id: @account.hash_id, id: @note)) do |form| %>
```

which works fine for New and correctly generates the form to edit but the action it puts into the edit form is still the "notes_path" I specify and not the 'edit_note_path' it needs to be.

Is there a way I can supply the :account_id so that form_for will correctly generate the route to what it needs to be instead of having duplicate _form partials, one where I am specifying "`url: notes_path(...`" and the other changed to "`url: edit_note_path(...`"?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you are asking: So the `form_for` line you provided is given a non-new `@note`. The `form_for` renders the form with content of this `@note`, but with the wrong `action` attribute? And this attribute I suspect directs to the `note POST`-path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [routing scope problem with form\_for (partial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371701/routing-scope-problem-with-form-for-partial)

Comment: on the edit form, the form action="/132133662/notes.10", and it should be action="/132133662/notes/10" so I get a "No route matches [PATCH] "/132133662/notes.10"" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path for edit something like below:

```
= form_for @note, :url => @note.persisted? ? edit_notes_path(account_id: @account.hash_id, id: @note) : notes_path(account_id: @account.hash_id, id: @note) do |f|
```